# Como faço para retornar apenas o maior valor dentro de um vetor?

Tags: c, array, funções

> Ele não verifica corretamente o maior. Para cada animal ele mostra o peso do animal como sendo o maior.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

#define TAM_MIN 1
#define TAM_MAX 500

/*
Síntese
Objetivo: Classificar animais de um zoológico segundo seu peso.
Entrada: Números de animais do zoológico, e para cada animal,
         o número de identificação e o peso em gramas.
Saída: A identificação e peso do animal mais pesado, a identificação
       e o peso do animal mais leve, e a quantidade de animais de
       peso menor que o peso médio de todos os animais.
*/


void mostra_resultados(int id_animal[TAM_MAX], float peso_animal[TAM_MAX]);
int le_valida_codigo_animal(char titulo[]);
float le_valida_peso_animal(char titulo[]);
int le_valida_inteiro(int valor_min, int valor_max, char *texto);

int main() {
    int i=1;
    int cod_animal[TAM_MAX]={0};
    float peso_animal[TAM_MAX]={0};

    printf("#--- Cadastro de animais ---#");
    int num_animais = le_valida_inteiro(TAM_MIN, TAM_MAX, "\nDigite o numero de animais do zoologico:");

    for (i; i <= num_animais; i++) {
        cod_animal[i] = le_valida_codigo_animal("Digite o codigo de identificacao dos animais:");
        peso_animal[i] = le_valida_peso_animal("Digite o peso (em gramas) do animal:");
        system("cls");
    }


    mostra_resultados(cod_animal,peso_animal);

    return 0;
}

//Valida o numero de animais(entre 1 e 500)
int le_valida_inteiro(int valor_min, int valor_max, char texto[]) {
    int num_animais = 0;

    while (1) {
        printf("%s", texto);
        scanf("%d", &num_animais);

        if (num_animais >= valor_min && num_animais <= valor_max) {
            return num_animais;
        }
        printf("\nValor invalido.\nDigite um numero entre %d e %d!", valor_min, valor_max);    
    }
}

//Valida o codigo do animal
int le_valida_codigo_animal(char titulo[]) {
    int cod=0;
    do{

        printf("%s", titulo);
        scanf("%d", &cod);

        if(cod<0){
            printf("Codigo nao pode ser negativo");
        }
    }while(cod<0);
    return cod;
}

float le_valida_peso_animal(char titulo[]){
    float peso_animal=0;
    do{

        printf("%s", titulo);
        scanf("%f", &peso_animal);

        if(peso_animal<0){
            printf("O peso nao pode ser menor que zero!");
        }

    }while(peso_animal<0);
    return peso_animal;
}


//Exibe o id e o peso do animal mais pesado
void mostra_resultados(int id_animal[TAM_MAX], float peso_animal[TAM_MAX]){
    int i;
    float mais_pesado[0];
    for(i=0;i<TAM_MAX;i++)
        {

            if(peso_animal[i] > mais_pesado[i])
                {
                    mais_pesado[i] = peso_animal[i];
                    printf("Codigo de identificao: %d\n", id_animal[i]);
                    printf("Animal mais pesado: %3.f gramas\n", mais_pesado[i]);

                }
        }


}
```

Comment: Acho que resolvi, galera!

Comment: Me enganei. Pensei ter resolvido, mas ainda está dando o mesmo problema. Eu acho que vou fazer testar separadamente cada caso: o mais pesado, o menos pesado, e a média dos pesos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A sua função mostra_resultados, está percorrendo, no for, até o valor 500, que é o valor declarado para o TAM_MAX. Portanto na chamada da função, passe o tamanho do vetor, que no caso seria o num_animais presente na sua função principal. Você pode também mudar a sintaxe na chamada da função e deixar os vetores da seguinte forma: int vetor[]. Ou usar int *vetor.

```
void mostra_resultados(int id_animal[], float peso_animal[], int num_animais){

    int i, j = 0;

    for(i=1;i<num_animais;i++)
        if(peso_animal[i] > peso_animal[j])
            j = i;

     printf("Codigo de identificao: %d\n", id_animal[j]);
     printf("Animal mais pesado: %3.f gramas\n", peso_animal[j]);

}
```

Acredito que assim o seu problema seria corrigido.
Quanto ao que mudei no for, o que está acontecendo é que, "chutei" uma possível posição para o animal mais pesado, que no caso foi a primeira posição, aí dentro do for ele vai verificar se tem algum animal no vetor que é mais pesado do que o que está nessa posição "chutada", caso tenha, o j vai receber essa posição.

Comment: Valeu, Rômulo! Só tem um problema: continua dando erro. O caso é que se, por exemplo, eu cadastrar dois animais, ele parece ler só o primeiro o valor no vetor e retornar ele como o maior. Eu não estou conseguindo resolver isso.

Comment: Não sei se é isso, mas pega o código com a modificação que eu mandei e na sua função principal, ao invés de iniciar o i com 1, começa com 0 e no for de leitura, coloca i < num_animais. Pois do jeito que está na função principal, a primeira posição está sendo pulada da leitura.

Comment: Cara, valeu mesmo! Funcionou direitinho. Agora é só verificar se o que o usuário digitou como código do animal não existe no vetor. Se existir, ele pede para que o usuário digite novamente. Vou voltar ao código aqui e terminar.

Comment: Show, qualquer coisa estou disponível.

Answer (score 0):

Amigo, `if(peso_animal[i] > mais_pesado[i])` perceba que você está incrementando o vetor mais_pesado sem ter nada na posição i para comparar, ou seja, eu tenho o peso do animal, mas não tenho nada na posição i para comparar com ele, acho que pra resolver esse problema nem precisaria do vetor mais_pesado[]